# Merging Items in CSV file

Tags: python, list, loops

I wrote this piece of code to merge two csv-files together, when they have one common name.
Somehow this code doesn't finish the whole list, but exits before.
What can I do, to stop it from exiting?

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import csv


f=filedialog.askopenfile(title="Open file",defaultextension=".csv", filetypes=(("CSV", "*.csv"),))
reader = csv.reader(f)
my_names= list(reader)

f=filedialog.askopenfile(title="Open file",defaultextension=".csv", filetypes=(("CSV", "*.csv"),))
reader = csv.reader(f)
my_subjects= list(reader)

new_file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(title="Save your results",defaultextension=".csv",  filetypes=(("CSV", "*.csv"),))
x=(len(my_names))
y=(len(my_subjects))


def matchymatchy():    
     for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
             if my_names[i][0]==my_subjects[j][0]:
                 new_file.write(my_names[i][0])
                 new_file.write(',')
                 new_file.write(my_names[i][1])
                 new_file.write(',')
                 new_file.write(my_subjects[j][1])
                 new_file.write('\n')
matchymatchy()
```

Comment: Any error messages? Are you sure that there aren't any unnecessary spaces or similar so that some entries aren't considered equal?

Comment: Nope. It randomly changes how many I items it merges.

Comment: So you can clearly tell, that it just stops randomly, as it writes half a line before the csv to end

Comment: Try to add `new_file.close()` as last line.